# replace value with image on load javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I create a table [image: Like this]

I want to change the status column with a green image if 778. and a red image if 779.
this is my html form code

```
<td> {{$penalty}}  </div>
<td> {{$Total)}}  </div>
<td> <span id="status">{{$status}}</span>   </div>
```

So, if people open the webpage, they will not see the status column with number again, but become an image.

```
var status = document.getElementById("status").innerHTML;
    if(status == 778){
        $('#status').attr('src','https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/31/Button_Icon_Green.svg/200px-Button_Icon_Green.svg.png');
    }else{
        $('#status').attr('src','https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/07/Button_Icon_Red.svg/200px-Button_Icon_Red.svg.png');
    }
```

Any javascript idea?
thanks in advance.

Comment: Do it angular way! Using _`ng-src`_.

Comment: replace your src="" to ng-src=""

Comment: You've added the `src` attribute to a span tag. You should be using an `img` tag and adding the attribute to that.

Comment: @Rayon @ Newbee Dev @ DVJex  I've changed src into ng-src, but it did not happen. still appeared as number 778

Comment: @ardigunawan — It is not about just chaning `ng-src`, you are suupose to manipulate src path as well..

Comment: @Rayon hmm can you give me an example code for this? tankyou

Comment: @ardigunawan — Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html is invalid, because:

1. `id` needs to be unique, not repeated in each row - use a class instead.
2. You're closing `<td>` elements with `</div>` tags.

Assuming you fix that, you then have the problem that your JS is trying to set the `src` of a `<span>` element, but you need an `<img>`. It is simple enough to insert the appropriate images using the [`:contains()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector) and the [`.html()` method](http://api.jquery.com/html):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.status:contains(778)').html("<img title='778' src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/31/Button_Icon_Green.svg/200px-Button_Icon_Green.svg.png'>");

  $('.status:contains(779)').html("<img title='779' src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/31/Button_Icon_Red.svg/200px-Button_Icon_Red.svg.png'>");

});
```

```css
img { height: 30px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td>{{$penalty}}</td><td>{{$Total)}}</td><td> <span class="status">778</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>{{$penalty}}</td><td>{{$Total)}}</td><td> <span class="status">779</span></td></tr>
<tr><td>{{$penalty}}</td><td>{{$Total)}}</td><td> <span class="status">778</span></td></tr>
</table>
```

I've set each `<img>` element's `title` attribute to either `778` or `779` so the user can see the values if they hover the mouse over the images. Note that using `.html()` will overwrite the text of the `<span>` with the `<img>`. If you want the numbers to be displayed beside the images then use `.append()` or `.prepend()` instead of `.html()`. If you want the images as background with the number on top of the image then do something with CSS like in [O_Z's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39696783/615754).

Answer (score 1):

If you can use CSS it's better then script.

```
<style>
    .im{
            background:url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/31/Button_Icon_Green.svg/200px-Button_Icon_Green.svg.png")  no-repeat;
            display:inline-block;
            height:10px;
            width:10px;
            background-size: contain;
        }
        .im[status="778"]{  
            background:url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/07/Button_Icon_Red.svg/200px-Button_Icon_Red.svg.png")  no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        }
           </style>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td> {{$penalty}}  </td>
    <td> {{$Total)}}  </td>
    <td> <span id="status" >{{$status}}</span>  <span class="im" status="{{$Total)}}"></span> </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

I added a property  `status="{{$Total)}}"` to the span which affects the CSS. This way you will not have on load issues, and it will work faster.

Here is the fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/ngdtfuej/
Just change the status property from 778 to something else,click the fiddle run, and see how red becomes green (or reverse it if U like).

Comment: @ardigunawan sorry, fixed it. U have a working fiddle now. I just reversed red and green but you get the point.

Comment: wow I'm so sorry, it also fixed my problem... I've try this thankyou so much @O_Z ... But I cannot mark 2 answer as accept here?

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`ng-src`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) with [`ternary operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

> *Using Angular markup like `{{hash}}` in a src attribute doesn't work right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The **ngSrc** directive solves this problem.*

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.elems = [{
    penalty: 0,
    total: 100,
    status: 778
  }, {
    penalty: 0,
    total: 200,
    status: 779
  }, {
    penalty: 0,
    total: 300,
    status: 778
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<table ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <tr>
    <th>Penalty</th>
    <th>Total</th>
    <th>Status</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="el in elems">
    <td>{{el.penalty}}</td>
    <td>{{el.total}}</td>
    <td> <span class="status">
      <img ng-src="{{el.status==778?'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/31/Button_Icon_Green.svg/200px-Button_Icon_Green.svg.png':'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/07/Button_Icon_Red.svg/200px-Button_Icon_Red.svg.png'}}" alt="">
    </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/strb541d/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I refer to these can not be used for looping

Comment: It could be used without loop as well.. I prefer to avoid `jQuery` with `Angular`.. It could depend on indivual choice...